Convert struct to [string]
I created a struct and want to convert to [[String]]
 var ucetPlatby = [struct_ucetPlatby]()

     struct struct_ucetPlatby {
            let id: Int
            let trasaid: Int
            let cena: Decimal
         
            }
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        ucetPlatby.append(.init(id: 1, trasaid: 1, cena: 33))
        ucetPlatby.append(.init(id: 3, trasaid: 1, cena: 44))
        ucetPlatby.append(.init(id: 4, trasaid: 1, cena: 55))
        
        print(ucetPlatby)

        }

...which results in:
[UD.ViewController.struct_ucetPlatby(id: 1, trasaid: 1, cena: 33), UD.ViewController.struct_ucetPlatby(id: 3, trasaid: 1, cena: 44), UD.ViewController.struct_ucetPlatby(id: 4, trasaid: 1, cena: 55)]

But how can I convert the struct object to something like [String]
[["1", "1", "33"], [["3", "1", "44"], [["4", "1", "55"]]


What is your goal? Why do you need to convert a struct to an array of strings?

It depends on how you want to format the numbers, but if you want the simplest approach, you would just use the default with "\(...)":
let stringVersion = ucetPlatby.map { ["\($0.id)", "\($0.trasaid)", "\($0.cena)"]}

The type of this is [[String]], which seems to be what you mean. The final output would be:
[["1", "1", "33"], ["3", "1", "44"], ["4", "1", "55"]]

(I believe your output is not quite what you meant; the brackets don't balance.)
